# Networkx shortest paths for two point layers

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx

I have a task to know the best way from houses to subway station.

[image]

There are three types of data on a picture below:

- orange dots are the entrances to subway stations
- violet dots are centerspoints of houses
- blue lines is a road network (let it firstly contain all types of
  road data)

The goal is to determine the shortest path from every house point to the closest subway entry and build a polyline layer.
I was thinking of using `arcpy` library for that but recently heard about `networkx` module, but right now I know only how to load data in graph, however, I cannot figure out how to look for desirable shortest path and what to do next in general.

Here is my draft for loading data to nx.Multigraph():

```
import arcpy
import networkx as nx 
import numpy as np

line_fc = 'lines'
points_hs = 'house_points'

graph = nx.MultiGraph()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_fc, 'SHAPE@') as sc:
    for row in sc:
        line_geom = row[0].getPart(0)
        list_geom_cors = np.array([(n.X, n.Y) for n in line_geom])
        graph.add_edges_from(list_geom_cors)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points_hs, 'SHAPE@XY') as sc:
    for row in sc:
        graph.add_node(row[0])
```

How to perform this task as correctly as possible?

Comment: Did you look at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html ?

Comment: It looks to me like in your graph construction, you are not including connectivity. In fact, your houses are not connected to anything, so there cannot be a shortest path from them. You need to connect them to your road network somehow. I would create artificial edges that connect each house to the nearest vertex in the road layer.

Comment: If you are using arcpy this would imply you have ArcMap, why are you not using the network dataset tools? This problem can be easily automated in model builder, no need to be using third party python modules.